# How to read a "long" number of bytes from file with RandomAccessFile in java

Tags: java, file, random-access

I'm trying to read a file, from a certain point in the file for a certain number of bytes.

`RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(_file, "r");
 randomAccessFile.seek(_offSet);

 randomAccessFile.read(buffer, 0, _size);`

Where the _offSet and _size type is "long".

The problem is, read method only takes "int". 
I overcame the offset problem by using "seek", how do I overcome the amount of bytes to read?

Comment: Wait.  Are you actually planning to read in more than 2 billion bytes?

Comment: ... but it has to be in one call? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no advantage I can see in trying to read more than 2 GB at once (other than simplicity) You can read more than 2 GB using multiple calls.

Comment: You can't even fit more than 2^31-1 elements in an array in Java.

Comment: Or ByteBuffer, but you can read into multiple byte[] or ByteBuffer in a collection or array.

Comment: I mean, to be fair, you could probably design a custom list or buffer implementation that internally uses multiple `ByteBuffer`s or arrays, but exposes an API that lets you index with `long`s.

Comment: Agreed, that is what I have done when trying to solve this problem.  I have also used memory mapped files to improve the efficiency of the reads and writes.

Answer (score 0):

Where would you read them into? You can't declare an array that big anyway. Your problem doesn't exist.

Comment: @choppy Doesn't make any difference. Each array is limited by Java to 2^31 bytes, i.e. the maximum integer, so `read()` having the same limit still isn't a problem.